# What effect does this CSS code have on a Wordpress Homepage?

Tags: css, wordpress

Hi there could someone take a look at this CSS code for a wordpress website

```
.lazy { display: none !important; }
```

The question: Does this code block images from being displayed on a wordpress homepage?

The problem: After adding CSS code to a site all images on the homepage are now not displaying. Before CSS code was added there were 50 images showing. No changes in plugins has occurred.

The desired effect: A change of CSS code that will allow all images on the homepage to display correctly.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Some images may have the `.lazy` class added to them, and since in the CSS you've provided there is `.lazy { display: none !important; }` they don't show. So try **deleting the code** and see if it solves the problem for you.